# How can we convert between a program using `call/cc` and a program using functions written in CPS?

Tags: programming-languages, continuations

The Scheme Programming Language says

> It turns out that any program that uses call/cc can be rewritten in CPS without call/cc, but a total rewrite of the program (sometimes including even system-defined primitives) might be necessary.

What are the general techniques to

- convert a program using call/cc to a program using functions written in CPS
- convert in the reverse direction?

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)? It has examples and shows how to perform the conversion.